# High Pass filter matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

Im working on spectrum analysis of wav file. I have plotting the spectrum of the whole frequency,but how can i plot just the high frequency of my file ? 
this is the code :

```
[a,fs] = wavread('ori1.wav');
ydft = fft(a);
ydft = ydft(1:length(a)/2+1);
freq = 0:fs/length(a):fs/2;
plot(freq,abs(ydft));
```

Comment: Have a look at `xlim`. Also please use `pwelch` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logical indexing:

```
a = randn(1,1000);
fs=10;
ydft = fft(a);
ydft = ydft(1:length(a)/2+1);
freq = 0:fs/length(a):fs/2;

lowestFrequencyToPlot = 2;
idxHigherFrequencies = freq >= lowestFrequencyToPlot;
plot(freq(idxHigherFrequencies),abs(ydft(idxHigherFrequencies)));
```

only the highest frequency can be plotted with `end`.

**Edit:** The array `freq` will consist of the frequencies like: [1,2,3,4,5].
If you compare such an array with a value -- say 3 -- (`freq > 3`), a vector is returned with 0 where the condition is false and 1 where the condition is true. This will be [0,0,0,1,1] (4 and 5 are bigger 3, others smaller).
This vector can then be used for logical indexing. `freq(freq>3)`will return the frequencies bigger than 3: [4,5].
`ydft(freq>3)` will return the values where the corresponding frequencies are bigger than 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have try the code and its work, but i still dont understand how it works, can you just explain me what does it mean please ?